# SQL and PHP datetime...most direct method

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm pulling from a datetime formatted field with mysql. I'm grabbing it with PHP, and I'm echoing it.  I need to change the format so it is human readable.  Ideally, I'd like to do this in PHP so I only need to change a single PHP file. If I do it in SQL, it'll effect multiple files.

Right now the output looks like this: `2011-05-30 21:28:37`.  I need it to look like this: `05/30/2011`.

Here's my code:

```
$query = "SELECT `fileName`, 
                 `imageName`,  
                 `imageCaption`, 
                 `imageDate` 
            FROM `images` 
           WHERE `gallery` = '$gallery' 
             AND `imageOrder` = '$featuredImage'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
  $fileName = mysql_result($result,$i,"fileName");
  $order = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageOrder");
  $imageName = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageName");
  $imageCaption = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageCaption");
  $date = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageDate");

  echo "$date";

  $i++;
}
```

Comment: You could use Zend_Date from Zend Framework, it can take any date you add to it, and print in any format you want. And you don't have to utilize the whole ZF library, you can use individual components in a stand-alone matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert datetime to another format with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396917/convert-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"imageDate"));
$display_date = date('d/m/Y', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the datetime field to a timestamp then pass it to PHP's date function to format it.

```
$date_to_time = strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"imageDate"));
$date = date('d/m/Y',$date_to_time);
```

Comment: Michael..thanks...I didn't know I had to convert it to a timestamp first...this is why i was lost all along....i used date() before but it was giving me the wrong date...thanks for your help...it works now

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$date = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageDate");
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
echo $objDate->format('m/d/Y');
```